# how to set default value query builder using controller in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, controller, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to make a Controller that will define the Default Value from query builder dynamically and directly from controller.

> for example :
>
> 1. in table users have column 'note' that the default value is 'this is old default note'
> 2. So step 2 in blade edit general setting there's an input value for define new default value for column 'note' in table 'users', so if i input in that form with 'this is new default note'. and every users registered will have value "this is new default value".

the problem is i'm confuse the flow to implement for that function. 
So this is my current code :

1. Code for GeneralSettingController.php :

   \DB::beginTransaction();

   ```
                   $updated = [
                       'max_sequence' => $max_sequence,
                       'latest_version' => $latest_version,
                       'minimum_version' => $minimum_version,
                   ];

                   $updateVersion = GeneralSetting::updateDataGeneralSettingCMS($updated);

                   \DB::commit();
                   if($updateVersion)
                   {
                       $status = "Update Succeed!";
                       return redirect()->route('setting.general_setting.detail')->with('error', $status);

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $status = "No Changes!";
                       return redirect()->route('setting.general_setting.detail')->with('error', $status);

                   }
   ```

   2. and this it the model class for: updateDataGeneralSettingCMS()

   public static function updateDataGeneralSettingCMS($updated)
   {
       //Get the fields to be updated
       $fields = [];
       foreach ($updated as $column => $var) {
           $value = $var;
           if($value !== null)
           {
               $fields['general_setting.' . $column] = $value;
           }
       }

   ```
   //Execute Update
   $count = \DB::table('general_setting')
       ->update($fields);

   return ($column > 0) ? true : false;
   ```